# How to get cookies from WKWebView?

Tags: ios, macos, cookies, wkwebview

How do I get *all* cookies from a WKWebView instance?

Here are what I've tried so far:

- I tried using `- [WKWebView evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:]` to evaluate `document.cookie` - unfortunately the result does not contain cookies that marked as [HttpOnly](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/).
- According to [Introducing the Modern WebKit API (WWDC 2014 Session 206)](http://asciiwwdc.com/2014/sessions/206?q=navigation%20response), it should be possible to get an `response` object from an instance of `WKNavigation`. However, according to the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigation_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKNavigation), `WKNavigation` does not contain any public method / property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question hasn't been answered after one year, I am posting my imperfect, but working solution:

You can have access to an `NSHTTPURLResponse` object in `- webView:decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:decisionHandler:` method defined on `WKNavigationDelegate`. You can later extract the cookies manually from the HTTP header:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationResponse:(WKNavigationResponse *)navigationResponse decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationResponsePolicy))decisionHandler {
    NSHTTPURLResponse* response = navigationResponse.response;
    NSArray *cookies = [NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
    for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) {
        // Do something with the cookie
    }

    decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicyAllow);
}
```

Please post your solution if you have a better one.

Comment: But I found some URLs will not call this callback. e.g. while the POST request.

Comment: Yes many URLs not call this call back e.g.  on for submit or POST request

Comment: Good one! Bu "newCookies" should be "cookies" for consistency.

Comment: In my case, every time i get empty "cookies" array.